# Problems with Audio Playback

Tags: sound, vpn, openvpn

I was previously using a VPN connection and realized I could watch localized video from the VPN Servers in different countries.

When I tried to watch Comedy Central using a VPN connection, the audio was slowed. It was clear that the website realized I was connecting from outside of the US.

Deterred, I stopped my VPN subscription and uninstalled the OpenVPN on my machine.

However, when going to a website called "mixer.com" that displays live feed videos of gaming websites, the audio distortion persisted.

Have my audio codex become corrupted? Has anyone else experienced this before?

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: I recorded some audio from Mixer.com so you can better understand what is happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTeF8JHf6Fc

Answer (score 0):

I was using "general.useragent.override" in Firefox to spoof a Microsoft Edge web browser. For some reason, when I removed the spoof and deleted my cookies the audio corrected itself.

Not sure if this is an Edge specific block or if it was a browser spoof problem.

Very strange to say the least.